# React Hooks: State is one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a modal that opens on click event. It gets the event data (date and time string) and displays it inside the modal. The problem is that my state is always one step behind. The content being displayed by the modal is always in the previous state. When I close the modal and reopen it, It does render the content but It is the previous event. How to solve this issue? am I using the react hooks wrong? I cannot post the whole code as It's quite large so I am just posting the parts where I am using hooks, please let me know if you need more information I will provide it.

```
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false)
  const [modelContent, setModalContent] = useState('')
  const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState('')
 

const handleEventAdd = (e) => {
    form.resetFields()
    setModalTitle('Add an Event')
    const event = _.cloneDeep(e)
      form.setFieldsValue({
        datePicker: dateString,
        timeRangePicker: [dateString, eventEnd.date],
      })
    }
    const content = () => (
      <div>
        <Form
          form={form}
          initialValues={{
            datePicker: moment(e.start),
            timeRangePicker: [moment(e.start), moment(e.end)],
          }}
        >
                  <Form.Item name="datePicker" label="Current Event Date">
                    <DatePicker
                      className="w-100"
                      format={preferredDateFormat}
                      onChange={setValueDate}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                form
                  .validateFields()
                  .then((values) => {
                    form.resetFields()
                  })
              }}
            >
              Add Event
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
    setModalContent(content)
    setIsModalVisible(true)
  }

const handleModalClose = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false)
    form.resetFields()
    setModalContent('')
  }
```

UPDATE::
my return function consists,

```
<Modal visible={isModalVisible} footer={null} onCancel={handleModalClose} title={modalTitle}>
    {modelContent}
  </Modal>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is due to the asynchronous behavior of `setState`. This method generates a "pending state transition" (see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) for more information). In order to solve this issue, you have two options:

1. use `ref` instead of `state`. In contrast to `state`, `ref` has synchronous behavior. I have developed an example for myself that you can check out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-engelbart-csz1c?file=/src/Ref.js:0-624). you can see that there is an asynchronous behavior in the state (dialog box vs. in webpage).
   [image]
2. You can explicitly pass the new state value as part of the event being raised.

Comment: Thank you for the info, It really helps. Could you please explain more on the second option? How would I explicitly pass the new state value based on my example.

Comment: happy to help. Sure, in the second option, you should provide your data directly to the function you want their data (for example I think you use this data in your `handleEventAdd`) and do not use `state` for data passing. let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I have updated my code so that you can see the render modal. So whenever the user triggers the click, It calls handleEventAdd and that sets my Modal as visible. How would I implement this correctly?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do and which state has a problem with your code, but let's consider you have an `int` variable and you try to set it using `setState`. Based on async behavior of the state, it would update in the next render so you should give it as an input directly to your function and then try to update it using `setState`

Comment: @WildThing did my answer help you?

Comment: Thank you I am still working on it, Basically I am using  Full Calendar with ReactJS, Whenever the user drags on the calendar the handleEventAdd function is triggered and it has "e" as a parameter, It has my start and end dates etc. And inside the handleEventAdd is my form, I generate the content there with JSX and render it onto my Modal using setModalContent and setIsModalVisible to true. Now I am not sure how to give it an input directly to my function so that It renders properly every time the user drags. I also set my modal content to empty string when user cancels the modal.

Comment: oh, I see, it can be challenging based on your application. However, I think you need to have a component as a `modal` and instead of checking `boolean` variable like `isModalVisible` pass its data directly (both its visibility and content), so you can handle your problem. If my answer helped you, I would be grateful if you tag it as a solution.

Comment: @abbasihsn I was trying this and can't get it to work, why is this different than above? `const seqnumRead = useRef(0); const seqnumWrite = useRef(0); // Click a session, bring up detail const selectSession_Click = (event, sessionId) => { const selectedData = data; let selSession = selectedData?.filter(s => s.SessionId == sessionId); SetSessionSelected(selSession[0]); refetch(); seqnumRead.current = result.payload.read_seqnum; seqnumWrite.current = result.payload.write_seqnum; }`

Comment: Have you seen the shared code? @MX313

Comment: @Abbasihsn I have, and have no idea why mine doesn't work :(   I got around it by accessing the result directly `result.payload.write_seqnum`