# useState wouldn't work asynchronously (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Building a recording app on React + Type Script. I tried to set state with getting stream, and it seems to be successfully gotten on console. But it couldn't be set up on `record target stream`.

```js
  const [recordTargetStream, setRecordTargetStream] = useState<MediaStream>()


  // click request permissions
  const requestPermissions = useCallback(async() => {
    const stream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    // stream is successfully gotten
    setRecordTargetStream(stream)
  }, [])


  const startRecording = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('start recording', recordTargetStream)
    // record target stream is undefined    
   ...

  return (
   <>
    <button onClick={() => requestPermissions()}>Request permissions</button>
    <button onClick={() => startRecording()}>Start recording</button>
   </>
  )
```

Comment: Try using a `useRef` to hold the stream because the UI is not dependent on this right you just need to save a value.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340219/react-hooks-state-is-one-step-behind/69340366?noredirect=1#comment122557677_69340366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `recordTargetStream` state as `useCallback` hook's dependencies.

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

> every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [recordTargetStream, setRecordTargetStream] = useState<MediaStream>()

  const requestPermissions = useCallback(async() => {
    const stream = await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
    setRecordTargetStream(stream)
  }, [])

  const startRecording = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('start recording', recordTargetStream)
  }, [recordTargetStream])

  return (
   <>
    <button onClick={() => requestPermissions()}>Request permissions</button>
    <button onClick={() => startRecording()}>Start recording</button>
   </>
  )
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import {fireEvent, render, screen, act} from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './';

describe('69354798', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mockMediaDevices = {
      getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test stream')
    }
    Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
      value: mockMediaDevices
    })
    render(<MyComponent/>)
    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Request permissions/))
    })
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Start recording/))
  })
})
```

test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/69354798/index.test.tsx
  69354798
    ✓ should pass (54 ms)

  console.log
    start recording test stream

      at stackoverflow/69354798/index.tsx:12:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.211 s
```